# Derived Column created in Visual Studio not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm working on a package in SSIS to populate a table after some joining and sorting processes.
I've created a Derived Column in Visual Studio to assign 0 to any null value in a column named fraud_flag using the following expression:

```
ISNULL(FRAUD_FLAG)?0:FRAUD_FLAG.
```

The package execution works fine when I run it within the Visual Studio and the destination table is properly populated. However, the table is populated with null values whenever I run the package in SQL Server. The values are set to null for the fraud_flag column even when the sources are not null.

Comment: Try deploying your working VS code to your SQL Server again.   This sounds like two different package versions to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using [REPLACENULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replacenull-ssis-expression) function:

```
REPLACENULL([fraud_flag],0)
```

and make sure that you are mapping the derived column to the destination